# Application does not close on release mode

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a windows form application on .net 3.5 C#.

Problem is when I run my application in debug mode and close the form , vs debugger also stopped, but when I run the same application in release mode and close the form, VS debugger does not stop.

Does someone has a clue about what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an `Event(FormClosing)` with the code:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Maybe there were some Threads behind that didn't Abort correctly or those threads caused an `unhandled exception`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Max Mommersteeg: Does it matter if I got only 2 whitespaces instead of 4?

Comment: issues is different application not properly working in release mode as i mentioned above